# Will Grow bags prevent soil pathogens from seeping into the bag from underneath?

Tags: diseases, soil, growth

I have an organic raised garden bed for tomatoes. Unfortunately a soil pathogen/fungi has damaged several of my plants this year. I could not find an environmentally safe way to treat soil pathogens other than resting the soil for a few years. Since I am in limited space, I thought that perhaps I could place 25 gallon grow bags on top of the raised garden bed. My concern is that the soil pathogens will seep into the bag's soil and I will have the same problem. Can anyone advise me on this, if I should place a plastic between the grow bag and the raised garden bed's soil, or am I overthinking this problem?

Comment: I would rather bag the suspect soil and/or pile it somewhere with lots of sun. The heat should accelerate sterilization effort. If bagged and space is really limited perhaps hanging the bags high could be an option.